# complete fill = 0 for all, not just specific columns

Tags: r, tidyr

Reading docs [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html) for complete()

> fill:
> A named list that for each variable supplies a single value to use
> instead of NA for missing combinations.

Example priovided:

```
df %>%
  complete(
    group,
    nesting(item_id, item_name),
    fill = list(value1 = 0, value2 = 99)
```

My question is, can I tell complete to fill all with 0? Tried just `fill = 0` which returned an error. I have more than 100 cols!

Comment: You can do `fill = across(starts_with("value"), ~0)`

Comment: If I could use a regex here such as * for everything that would be great

Comment: `across(everything(), ~0)` for all columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the case you want to fill all columns,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  complete(trial_day = 1:14) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), replace_na, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, on my read data I get this error with that: `complete(trial_day = 1:14, fill = across(everything(), ~0))
Error in `dplyr::summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = complete(data = dplyr::cur_data(), ..., fill = fill, explicit =
  explicit)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: nextzen_id = "0000bce6-ed4f-4364-9bea-7c395f696489", trial_plan =
  "PortfolioPlus", signup_medium = "referral".
Caused by error in `replace_na()`:
! `replace` must be a list.
Backtrace:
  1. tidyr::complete(...)
 12. tidyr:::complete.data.`

Comment: Ahh It wants a list at the `fill`. Maybe do it with mutate, after...something like `complete(trial_day = 1:14) %>% mutate(across(everything(), replace_na, 0))`